# How to add multiple Nestjs RoleGuards in controllers

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, roles, guard

I have role guard for ADMIN, SUPERADMIN, USER, MODERATORS,

This is an example of one of the guards. An Admin guard in the case. They are working as I expected but I can't add multiple guards in the controller

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

@/Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
 constructor() { }

 canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
 const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
 const user = request.user;

 if (user.usertype == 'Admin') {
 return true;
        }
 throw new HttpException('Unauthorized access', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

in my controllers, I have this decorator

```
 
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), AdminGuard)
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), AdminGuard, SuperAdminGuard)
```

or

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), [AdminGuard, SuperAdminGuard, UserGuard])
```

or

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), AdminGuard || SuperAdminGuard || UserGuard])
```

None of the above implementations worked. Is there a better way to go about it? Maybe there is something I am not doing right. I have checked the docs but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: In `@UseGuards(A, B, C)`, if `A` returns false, it won't go to `B`. So in order to proceed, all must return true. You may want to handle like this: `if (user.usertype === 'Admin' || user.usertype) { return true }` so the next guard can be invoked.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I tried it out. But I will go for @kim-kern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to create one generic `RolesGuard` and define the required roles per controller or route handler with custom metadata:

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const userType = request.user.userType;
    return roles.some(r => r === userType);

  }
}
```

Custom decorator to set the required roles:

```
export const Roles = (...roles: string[]) => SetMetadata('roles', roles);
```

#### How to use it?

Now you can define the required roles as follows:

```
// For this route you need either Superadmin or Admin privileges
@Roles('Superadmin', 'Admin')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach rather than what Kim has answered is to use `Mixin`. The mixin concept is used by the `AuthGuard` itself.

```js
export const UserTypeGuard: (...types: string[]) => CanActivate = createUserTypeGuard;

function createUserTypeGuard(...types: string[]) {
    class MixinUserTypeGuard implements CanActivate {
        canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
            const user = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
            return types.some(type => user.userType === type);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), UserTypeGuard('SuperAdmin', 'Admin'))
```